# How to fix issue with Nokogiri in RubyMine in order to run Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, rubymine-7

I have had these issues now for several months. I am trying to run a Rails application using the RubyMine IDE on Windows 8. I have tried running a Rails application on Mac OS through RubyMine and have experienced the exact same problem which is a error caused from 'missing gems' or something thereof.

In the end I resorted to make my Rails applications via the terminal, which worked PERFECTLY. Now that all I have is my PC with Windows 8, I am determined to solve all issues in regards to me running a Rails application through RubyMine!

I have been able to progress further this time but my current issue is, when ever use

```
Run > Run 'Development: test_rails_app'
```

I get:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\RubyMine 7.0.4\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Ruby22-x64\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) D:/Programming/RUBY/RubyMine/test_rails_app/bin/rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:32:in `<module:TextHelper>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:29:in `<module:Helpers>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:6:in `<module:ActionView>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:18:in `<module:FormTagHelper>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:14:in `<module:Helpers>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:8:in `<module:ActionView>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:50:in `<module:Helpers>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:7:in `<module:LegacyAssetTagHelper>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<module:Rails>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:4:in `<module:Sprockets>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:45:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:45:in `<module:Helper>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:7:in `<module:Rails>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:6:in `<module:Sprockets>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:6:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
from D:/Programming/RUBY/RubyMine/test_rails_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from D:/Programming/RUBY/RubyMine/test_rails_app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
from D:/Programming/RUBY/RubyMine/test_rails_app/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'

  Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Update:**
Following on from the suggestion in the comments where I learned the version of Ruby I was using was not supported in nokogiri gem I was using, I decided to try again using ruby 2.0.0

I'm still having issues..
the ruby gems I am using are located in

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems
```

but everytime I run 'bundle install' they are being installed here!

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems
```

how do I change the directory that the gems are being installed to?

Comment: Sounds like you might be running into https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1256

Comment: This sounds exactly like my issue! I will try using ruby versions 1.9.3, 2.0.0 or 2.1.3 and get back with the results!

Comment: Having another issue now. see update :(